# Efficient df insertion from generator

Tags: python, pandas, token, generator

I am building a data-matching script which joins two datasets on tokens.  The code runs but with a large number of records and tokenized fields it takes a very long time to complete.  I'm looking for suggestions as to how to make this more computationally efficient.

I will note the area which performs poorly but first some context:

```
#example df
d = {'id': [3,6], 'Org_Name': ['Acme Co Inc.', 'Buy Cats Here Inc'], 'Address': ['123 Hammond Lane, Washington, DC', 'Washington, DC 20456']}
left_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# example tokenizer
def tokenize_name(name):
    if isinstance(name, basestring) is True:
        clean_name = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() else ' ' for c in name)
        return clean_name.lower().split()
    else:
        return name

#tokenizers assigned to columns
left_tokenizers = [
    ('Org_Name', tokenize_name),
    ('Address', tokenize_name)
]

#example token dictionary
tokens_dct = {
    'acme':1,
    'co':1,
    'inc':0,
    'buy':1,
    'cats':1,
    'here':1,
    '123':1,
    'hammond':1,
    'lane':0,
    'washington':1,
    'dc':1,
    '20456':1
}

#this is the generator function used to create token/ID pairs
def prepare_join_keys(df, tokenizers):
    for source_column, tokenizer in tokenizers:
        if source_column in df.columns:
            for index, record in enumerate(df[source_column]):
                if isinstance(record, numbers.Integral) is False: #control for longs
                    if isinstance(record, float) is False: #control for nans
                        for token in tokenizer(record):
                            if tokens_dct[token] == 1: #tokenize only for tokens present in dictionary with value 1
                                yield (token, df.iloc[index]['id'])

# THIS CODE TAKES A LONG TIME TO RUN
left_keyed = pd.DataFrame(columns=('token', 'id'))
for item in prepare_join_keys(left_df, left_tokenizers):
    left_keyed.loc[len(left_keyed)] = item

left_keyed
```

A dictionary is used to trim off common tokens (LLC, Corp, www, etc.) but still this can be computationally expensive with a lot of tokens.  I wonder, is the way I am inserting generated token/ID pairs into dataframe inefficient?  Is there a better way to do this?  Also wondering if I'm committing a computational sin by using if instead of elif.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Iterating through the items in a dataframe will be slow.

Comment: Your better off iterating through a list and then use a `df`

Comment: can you provide a short example?

Comment: I've updated the code with some example df and token dictionary, now you should be able to run the code.  Thanks for comments so far; it sounds like my approach using df may be the culprit.  But do you mean that source data needs to be split into lists, or the way I am inserting into a df is why this is so time consuming?

Comment: Also, just accessing `df.iloc[index]['id']` is very inefficient in a loop. `.iloc` and `.loc`  accessors are for accessing *many rows*. There's tons of overhead for a single value, and it creates intermediate df-objects they way you are doing it. Use `.iat` and `.at` for a *single* value. But yeah, never build up a data-frame in a loop. It has to reallocate the underlying buffer every iteration. It's extremely inefficient. Why are you even using pandas here to begin with? Anyway, just use a list and use that list to build the dataframe if you really need it (which you probably dont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no real reason to do this in pandas.  Its much more efficient to use a prebuilt tokenizer.  This should do what you want.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# since you have a predefined vocabulary, you can fix it here
vocabulary = np.array([w for w, b in tokens_dct.items() if b])
cv = CountVectorizer( vocabulary=vocabulary)

frame_list = []
for colname in ['Org_Name', 'Address']:
    tokenmapping = cv.fit_transform(left_df[colname])
    df_row, token_id = tokenmapping.nonzero()

    frame_list.append(pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([vocabulary[token_id], left_df['id'].values[df_row]]).T, columns = ['token', 'id']))

left_keyed = pd.concat(frame_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, this put me in the right direction.  One question, I tried this code as well as identical code except for "if b == 1" and observed no difference in behavior.  Why would this be?